# Issue In Zipping Pcap Files

Tags: java, android

I am generating pcap files and need to zip it. Currently i am able to generate and store the pcap file in local storage. 
for zipping i am using below code:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    try {
        zipFilePath = urls[0];
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFilePath + ".zip");
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
        ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(urls[1]);
        zos.putNextEntry(ze);
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(zipFilePath);

        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        zos.closeEntry();
        //remember close it
        zos.close();
        return zipFilePath + ".zip";
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

I am getting `file not found` exception at `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFilePath + ".zip");`